# Why am I getting "AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'savefig'"?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, matplotlib, attributeerror

---

***Edit 3/15/2017 12:00 PM CDT:***  I have managed to fix the error in the program and complete the program as it was designed. I would like to thank berna1111 and TigerhawkT3 for their answer submissions, as they allowed me to complete this program. Thanks again, Stack Overflow!

---

I am attempting to save a series of array-built histograms (arrays made with numpy and histograms using matplotlib) to .png type files. I am receiving the following error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Ryan/PycharmProjects/NWS/weather_data.py", line 475, in <module>
    figure1.savefig("{}_temperature.png".format(filename))
AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'savefig'
```

The section the error refers to is below:

```
figure1 = plt.hist(temperature_graph_array, color="blue")
figure2 = plt.hist(feelslike_graph_array, color="blue")
figure3 = plt.hist(windspeed_graph_array, color="blue")
figure4 = plt.hist(windgustspeed_graph_array, color="blue")
figure5 = plt.hist(pressure_graph_array, color="blue")
figure6 = plt.hist(humidity_graph_array, color="blue")

figure1.savefig("{}_temperature.png".format(filename), format='png')
figure2.savefig("{}_feelslike.png".format(filename), format='png')
figure3.savefig("{}_windspeed.png".format(filename), format='png')
figure4.savefig("{}_windgustspeed.png".format(filename), format='png')
figure5.savefig("{}_pressure.png".format(filename), format='png')
figure6.savefig("{}_humidity.png".format(filename), format='png')
```

Why am I receiving this error, and how can I fix it? If someone could let me know I would greatly appreciate it.

---

***Notes:***

- I have done some google searching and found a few similar errors, but none where the figure was interpreted as a tuple. I do not understand where the tuple part is coming from.
- The "_graph_array" items in the histogram creation steps are arrays of dimensions 10 long, 1 tall. 10 total items inside, designated as type Float.
- The "filename" variable in the saving step represents a string containing the date and time.

---

Comment: `plt.hist` does not return a `figure` instace, you should create a figure (`fig1 = plt.figure()`), an axis on it (`ax1 = fig1.add_subplots(111)`) and then draw on the axis (`ax1.hist(...)`). At that point you should be able to save the figure (`fig1.savefig(...)`). Will post an answer after testing.

Comment: Correction: `ax1 = fig1.add_subplot(111)`, not `ax1 = fig1.add_subplot`*s*`(111)`!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've adapted your code and took the liberty to change the several lines creating a figure by list in comprehension of for loops:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
# should be equal when using .pylab
import numpy.random as rnd

# generate_data
n_points = 1000
temperature_graph_array = rnd.random(n_points)
feelslike_graph_array = rnd.random(n_points)
windspeed_graph_array = rnd.random(n_points)
windgustspeed_graph_array = rnd.random(n_points)
pressure_graph_array = rnd.random(n_points)
humidity_graph_array = rnd.random(n_points)
list_of_data = [temperature_graph_array,
                feelslike_graph_array,
                windspeed_graph_array,
                windgustspeed_graph_array,
                pressure_graph_array,
                humidity_graph_array]
list_of_names = ['temperature',
                 'feelslike',
                 'windspeed',
                 'windgustspeed',
                 'pressure',
                 'humidity']

# create the figures:
#figure1 = plt.figure()
#figure2 = plt.figure()
#figure3 = plt.figure()
#figure4 = plt.figure()
#figure5 = plt.figure()
#figure6 = plt.figure()
#list_of_figs = [figure1, figure2, figure3, figure4, figure5, figure6]
## could be:
list_of_figs = [plt.figure() for i in range(6)]

# create the axis:
#ax1 = figure1.add_subplot(111)
#ax2 = figure2.add_subplot(111)
#ax3 = figure3.add_subplot(111)
#ax4 = figure4.add_subplot(111)
#ax5 = figure5.add_subplot(111)
#ax6 = figure6.add_subplot(111)
#list_of_axis = [ax1, ax2, ax3, ax4, ax5, ax6]
## could be:
list_of_axis = [fig.add_subplot(111) for fig in list_of_figs]

# plot the histograms
# notice `plt.hist` returns a tuple (n, bins, patches) or
# ([n0, n1, ...], bins, [patches0, patches1,...]) if the input
# contains multiple data
#hist1 = ax1.hist(temperature_graph_array, color="blue")
#hist2 = ax2.hist(feelslike_graph_array, color="blue")
#hist3 = ax3.hist(windspeed_graph_array, color="blue")
#hist4 = ax4.hist(windgustspeed_graph_array, color="blue")
#hist5 = ax5.hist(pressure_graph_array, color="blue")
#hist6 = ax6.hist(humidity_graph_array, color="blue")
#list_of_hists = [hist1, hist2, hist3, hist4, hist5, hist6]
## could be:
list_of_hists = []
for i, ax in enumerate(list_of_axis):
    list_of_hists.append(ax.hist(list_of_data[i], color="blue"))

filename = 'output_graph'
for i, fig in enumerate(list_of_figs):
    name = list_of_names[i].capitalize()
    list_of_axis[i].set_title(name)
    fig.tight_layout()
    fig.savefig("{}_{}.png".format(filename,name), format='png')
```

Will not post the resulting figures, but this gives me 6 little .png files in the same folder as the script.

Even better, you can use a function to do all that to your data:

```
def save_hist(data, name, filename):
    fig = plt.figure()
    ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
    ax.hist(data, color="blue")
    ax.set_title(name)
    fig.tight_layout()
    fig.savefig("{}_{}.png".format(filename,name), format='png')
    plt.close(fig)

filename = 'output_graph_2'
for data, name in zip(list_of_data, list_of_names):
    save_hist(data, name, filename)
```

Answer (score 4):

From the [documentation for `matplotlib.pyplot.hist`](http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.hist):

> The return value is a tuple (`n`, `bins`, `patches`) or ([`n0`, `n1`, ...], `bins`, [`patches0`, `patches1`,...]) if the input contains multiple data.

From the [documentation for `matplotlib.pyplot.savefig`](http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.savefig):

> Save the current figure.

It looks like you should call `savefig` in the same way you call `hist`, not on the result of the `hist` call.

```
plt.savefig("{}_temperature.png".format(filename), format='png')
...
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, however this does not work. When running the "hist" function, that step actually creates the graphs. Without the creation of the graphs, there are no graphs to save. Your solution simply removes the creation of the graphs.

Comment: @RyanWitek - Yes, you need to call `hist()` and then `savefig()`, but `savefig` is a method of `matplotlib.pyplot`, not a method of what `hist()` returns (a tuple).